# Creating a matrix and searching for values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

If possible can someone help me figure this out, please?
I have the below matrix.

[image]

1. I need to be able to create the matrix in Python
2. I want to look up a column header and a row to find the appropriate y or n.

so where `xyz` and `ttt` intersect, I want the function to return `y`

Comment: Can you provide a code that you tried? Or this is a csv file?

Comment: yes the matrix is in a csv file at present.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python read CSV file", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: This is a zero-effort off topic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas` to read the file and it will return a `DataFrame.`Dataframe` is a 2D data structure that supports column,row labelling ( looks like a table).

```
import pandas as pd

print(pd.read_csv("file.txt"))
```

check [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas dataframes, and read that data in like a csv:

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv('out77.txt').set_index('0')
df
```

output:

```
    xyz abc cdf efg
0                  
qqq   y   y   n   y
stv   n   y   y   n
ttt   y   y   y   y
ppp   n   y   n   y
```

Then you can lookup like this:

```
df['xyz']['ttt']                                                                                                                                                      
# 'y'
```

Comment: thanks very much, i might be pushing my luck but if i imported the CSV into my DB could I read the table in my DB the same as reading the csv to achieve the same result?

Comment: If your database can give you a json back, you can read in json

Answer (score 1):

The `pandas` library is a great solution to this, but if you need to do it without a third-party library, here's a way: we'll represent the matrix as a dictionary of dictionaries.

```py
def split_on_commas(line):
    parts = [ s.strip() for s in line.split(',') ]
    return parts[0], parts[1:]

with open('filename.csv') as f:
    first_line = next(f)
    _, cols = split_on_commas(first_line)
    matrix = dict()

    for row in f:
        r, entries = split_on_commas(row)
        matrix[r] = { c: (x == 'y') for c, x in zip(cols, entries) }
```

The matrix will contain Booleans indexed by row, then by column, so for example:

```py
>>> matrix['ttt']['xyz']
True
```